# Fancybox 2 Not Loading in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I have FancyBox installed in my Rails 3.2 app's vendor assets directories (e.g. the jquery.fancybox.pack.js, jquery.fancybox.css, and the associated images in their respective directories within the vendor assets folder, none of the extras).

The javascript and CSS assets are loaded in both the application.js and application.css files in the asset pipeline. And, I've tested and confirmed that they are indeed working, because an image pops up properly when clicked.

The problem is that a YouTube video modal won't load. Instead, it just shows the loading GIF that flickers every second or so.

Here's the jQuery (CoffeeScript) code:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".videopopup").fancybox
    maxWidth: 800
    maxHeight: 600
    fitToView: false
    width: '70%'
    height: '70%'
    autoSize: false
    closeClick: false
    openEffect: 'none'
    closeEffect: 'none'
  return
```

And here's the link code within the page:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('thumbnail.png', alt: 'Thumbnail', class: "responsive"), 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/myvideocode?fs=1&autoplay=1', class: 'videopopup', title: 'My Video' %>
```

I am running this on localhost, which could be the problem. In Chrome, I looked at the console and found the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.youtube.com/embed/myvideocode?fs=1&autoplay=1. Origin `http://localhost:3000` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Does anyone know what this error means? I've seen a few SO questions about this error, but no specific solutions on how to get past it in Rails. Or, am I missing something?

Comment: why you don't try testing in a server environment a answer yourself ?  ;) ... I bet that testing locally has to do with the issue.

Comment: I was hoping there was an easier answer :) I can't deploy the app to production without knowing 100% and it's a bit of a hassle to setup a whole new server/app just to troubleshoot one problem. I was hoping that someone had a similar experience and would be able to tell me one way or the other.

Comment: then I will test it to see if I can reproduce the issue .... but with a little bit of time (jammed right now)

Comment: BTW, since you are targeting youtube `embed` mode, have you tried adding the class `fancybox.iframe` like `class: 'videopopup fancybox.iframe'` ?... then it could run both locally or in a server alike.

Comment: That's a great idea- I'll give it a shot now!

Comment: I still get the same error with the `fancybox.iframe`... I can try and reproduce the issue as well tomorrow and see if it's localhost causing the problem.

Comment: I tested it and it works "locally" using class ="videopopup fancybox.iframe" ... maybe you need to clear your cache

Comment: That works!! Thank you SO much!! If you put that as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the error message you have posted is self explaining - ajax requests are not allowed due to security restrictions.

The real question would be - why is the script making an ajax request, as it should create an iframe. Looks like the script can not guess content type and, as JFK has already mentioned, you can help by adding classname "fancybox.iframe".